# How to write a function in ReasonML with a type variable to accept any type of parameter?

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml, reason

I notice a very strange behavior with type inference mechanism in ReasonML. I have a record containing identify function. When I use the record instance directly, the compiler doesn't complain. But when I pass the record to another function and try to invoke identity function, then type inference complains:

```
type idRecord('a) = {
  // idFn can take any type.
  idFn: 'a => 'a
};

let myRecord: idRecord('a) = {
  idFn: anyVal => anyVal
};

// WORKS ABSOLUTELY FINE
let x1 = myRecord.idFn(10);
let x2 = myRecord.idFn("Something");

let runProgram = (program: idRecord('a)) => {

  let _y1 = program.idFn(10);

  // BOOM: ERROR
  // This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type int
  let _y2 = program.idFn("Something");
}

runProgram(myRecord);
```

The error is:

> This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type int

What do I need to make type inference happy to accept any type of argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on the type inference algorithm, but to me it seems odd that it works in the first case since the type variable is defined on the record, not just for the function. Consider what would happen if you added another field to `idRecord` of type `'a`:

```
type idRecord('a) = {
  idFn: 'a => 'a,
  value: 'a
};
```

I suspect it works due to a relaxation of the type inference rules that only works in some very limited conditions which does not include the record being a function argument.

In any case, the solution is simple: Remove the type variable from the record and universally quantify `'a` in the function type signature:

```
type idRecord = {
  idFn: 'a. 'a => 'a
};
```

`'a.`, which should be read "for all `'a`s", ensures that `'a` is fully polymorphic and will accept any type.

Answer (score 5):

The root issue is that your function `runProgram` is second-rank polymorphic, or in other words using polymorphic function as argument is a bit complicated.

More seriously, in fantasy syntax, the type of `runProgram` would be `('a. 'a => 'a)=> unit` where `'a. 'a => 'a` denotes a function that is required to work for any `'a`. This contrasts with a function like

```
let apply: 'a. ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = (f, x) => f(x)
```

where the type variable `'a` is introduced first (in prenex position), and then the function argument is required to work only on this specific type `'a`. For instance

```
 let two = apply( (x)=> 1 + x, 1)
```

is valid even if `(x)=> 1 + x` only works for integer. Whereas

```
 let fail = runProgram((x) => 1 + x)
```

fails because `(x) => 1 + x` cannot work with strings.

Going back to your type inference problem, the reason why the typechecker fails to infer the type that you had in mind is that type inference and higher-rank polymorphism does not mesh well (more precisely type inference is undecidable in presence of higher-rank polymorphism). To understand why, consider this simple function

```
let ambiguous(f,x) = f(1)+f(x)
```

The type inferred by the type checker for `ambiguous` is `(int=>int)=>int=>int`.
However, if I replace `f` with a record with a polymorphic field (which is one of the two ways to write higher-order polymorphic function in OCaml)

```
type const = {f:'a. 'a => int}
let ambiguous({f},x) = f(1)+f(x)
```

the type of `ambiguous` (in fantasy syntax) becomes `('a.'a=>int)=>'a=>int`. In other words, if the type inference were able to infer higher-rank polymorphism it would have to decide between `('a.'a=>int)=>'a=>int` and `(int=>int)=>int=>int`. And there is no clear winner between the two types: the first type has a strong constraint on its first argument and is laxer on its second argument, and the second type is exactly the opposite. This is a generic problem with higher-rank polymorphism: there is a lot of potential choices without an obvious best choice.

That's why the typecheker requires to be quite explicit when writing higher-rank polymorphic function:

```
type program = { program: 'a. 'a => 'a }
let runProgram = ({program}) => {
  let _y1 = program(10);
  let _y2 = program("Something");
}
```

See also the OCaml manual at http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/polymorphism.html#sec61 .